# How to properly present McNemar's Test Statistics

Tags: p-value, interpretation, presentation

I have read an [article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3173385/table/T2/) and I wonder if that is a proper way to present a McNemar's Test statistics.

The study try to measure the change in knowledge before and after a lesson. They performed McNemar's test to calculate the p-value, and tabulate it.

I don't feel comfortable when reading the table because:

McNemar's test just shows if the difference in the count of the discordant pairs (Pre-T + Post-F) OR (Pre-F + Post-T) are statistically significant. It does not give any clue on whether the question improve or worsen attendees' knowledge. But the table seems to claim that the education program caused an increased number of attendees improving their knowledge, support by McNemar's test, which I don't feel comfortable about that statement.

I wonder if the count of the discordant pairs are included in the table (number of Pre-T + Post-F and number of Pre-F + Post-T), will give a different picture.

My question is:

By aggregating the counts in the 2x2 table into Pre-correct count and Post-correct and then present it with the McNemar's test statistics, is it appropriate? I tried to find one similar article in Lancet or NEMJ but I can't.

If it is not appropriate, how can it be presented in a more proper way? Thanks.

Comment: I don’t get it. Do you mean that they should use a unilateral test instead? I think that: yes!

Comment: @Elvis: no, what I mean is the table seems to lure people to misinterpret the p-value as a support that more attendees answered post question correctly after attending the lesson

Comment: Well, I think the low $p$-values support this when $\Delta > 0$, yes. Low $p$-values with $\Delta < 0$ would support that less attendees answered correctly after the lesson. It’s a problem to interpret the direction of an effect detect through a bilateral test, theoretically speaking, if you prefer you can compute the odds of answering well before and after the lessons, and an odds ratio with a 95% confidence interval...